# mariadb galera cluster could support in memory table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, galera, in-memory-tables

I want to change my cluster to mariadb innodb galera cluster
and need to know does this replication support in memory tables
bbefore this i have mysql in my cluster but need to use mariadb with innodb search engine
bbut the problem is these in memory table
does this replication end to an error?

allowing in memory table in mariadb galera cluster

Comment: As other guys answered, It is not possible to sync `MyISAM` and `MEMORY`, So i suggest to use beside galera redis cluster or elastic, on your requirement!

Comment: thanks, yes exactly redis is a good choice

Answer (score 3):

Galera is all about HA (High Avility).  The Query Cache, MyISAM, and MEMORY-table are not practical for a situation where multiple nodes are expected to stay perfectly in sync.

I do not expect any of those to be implemented in the future.;

Please explain what you want `MEMORY` for.  Maybe we can suggest a workaround.

Comment: thanks for answering.. the consistency of data is not important here if we lost them.. I only want to know this such replication let us do transaction on table when they are in memory or memory table. when we have galera cluster with mariadb

Comment: "Transaction" do not apply MyISAM or MEMORY.  MyISAM fails on A,C,I; MEMORY fails on all of the ACID features of InnoDB.  (I think.)  Or, maybe, you have a different meaning for "transaction"?

Comment: no exactly I mean crud operation in my galera cluster when using innodb...if I can't use this replication. do you think using redis for memory table ? .... because I have in-memory table

Comment: A read-only table in InnoDB is effectively the same as a MEMORY table because of the caching that InnoDB automatically does.  What is _your_ purpose for using MEMORY?

Comment: The purpose of using table with engine=memory is only because of the speed, and it is faster than tables with engine=InnoDB

Comment: If you have multiple connections, InnoDB is sometimes faster -- because of row locking vs table locking.